# Unable to compile solution, nuget issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

unable to compile .net solution, these errors started to happen from couple of days, it was working before. Nuget settings allow missing stuff to be downloaded when solution is built


Could not find file 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\nuget\icafosw4.gqd\NuGet.exe'.

The command ""C:\Projects\dev\Web\TestApp.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\Projects\dev\xxx\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\Projects\dev\Web\TestApp\ "" exited with code 1.

Any Idea, how to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like antivirus was deleting the files, disabled antivirus and it works now